# How to add an item into a particular index of a Laravel eloquent collection

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to add an item in a collection which is paginated.

`return Entries::online()->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
       ->paginate(12);`

But I want it to be always on third index.
I know how to add an entry on the end of a collection, but how do I put it on the specific index.
Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.

One solution is to splice your collection at the index, then create a new collection, copy the collection before the index, prepend your new item and, at the end, copy the rest of your collection into the new one.

```
$afterIndex = $newsItems->splice($index);
$newItensCollections = $newsItems;
$newItensCollections->prepend($yourNewItem);
$newItensCollections->union($afterIndex);
```

To splice: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-splice

To prepend: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-prepend

To copy the arrays: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-union